# Polynomial Set Membership Algorithms

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, algorithms

I am trying to write a program that takes in a polynomial $P(x,y)$ and determine if it is a member of the following set of polynomials. Given a set of polynomials 
$$
s = \{x, 1-x, y, 1-y, x-xy, y-xy, 1-x-y+xy, xy\} = \{p_1,p_2,...p_8\}
$$
we define the set $S$ to be 
$$
S = \{c_1p_1+c_2p_2+...+c_8p_8+1 \mid c_1,c_2,...,c_8\geq0\}
$$

Is there an algorithm or method to determine whether $P(x,y)\in S$ for any given polynomial? Important to note that this polynomial is simplified.

Comment: "fits into" is linearly dependent or...?

Comment: @Holo, I meant "is a member of". Sorry changed my wording

Comment: I think it will probably be easier to check whether or not $P-1\in Span (s)$ but I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any polynomial in $S$ must have terms in $\{1,x,y,xy\}$, so be of the form 
$$  a + b x + c y + d xy  \text{,}  \tag{I}$$
for $a,b,c,d$ in whatever set the $c_i$ live in (which is unspecified in your problem statement).
If a polynomial has a term not in the list, it cannot be in $S$.  From the forms given in $s$, we find \begin{align*}
d &= -c_5 -c_6 +c_7 +c_8 \\
c &=  c_3 -c_4 +c_6 -c_7 \\
b &=  c_1 -c_2 +c_5 -c_7 \\
a &=  c_2 +c_4 +c_7 +1  \tag{LP}
\end{align*}
From the condition on the $c_i$, one piece of low-hanging fruit is that $a \geq 1$ is necessary.

Solving this linear system for $c_5, \dots, c_8$, we have \begin{align*}
c_5 &= -1 +a +b -c_1 -c_4  \\
c_6 &= -1 +a +c -c_2 -c_3  \\
c_7 &= -1 +a -c_2 -c_4 \\
c_8 &= -1+a+b+c+d-c_1-c_3
\end{align*}
With this, the question is recast as: are there nonnegative $c_1, \dots, c_4$ making $c_5, \dots, c_8$ nonnegative.  Again, we have low-hanging fruit.  From each equation, in order from top to bottom, \begin{align*}
a+b &\geq 1  &  0 &\leq c_1 + c_4 \leq a+b-1  \\
a+c &\geq 1  &  0 &\leq c_2 + c_3 \leq a+c-1  \\
a   &\geq 1  &  0 &\leq c_2 + c_4 \leq a  -1  \\
a+b+c+d &\geq 1  &  0 &\leq c_1 + c_3 \leq a+b+c+d-1  \tag{II}
\end{align*}
In each line, if the left column inequality is satisfied, the right column inequality is satisfiable (by, at the very least setting $c_1 = \cdots = c_4 = 0$), so the polynomial is in $S$.  If any inequality in the left column is not satisfied, then the corresponding member of $c_5,\dots,c_8$ is negative, so the polynomial is not in $S$.

Summary of algorithm:

```
Check that the polynomial is in the span of {1, x, y, xy}, allowing any signs for coefficients.  
    If not, polynomial is not in S.
Assign a,b,c,d as in (I).
Check the inequalities in the left column of (II).  
    If all are satisfied, the polynomial is in S.  
    If any is/are not satisfied, the polynomial is not in S.
```

Although it is difficult in general to [determine if a linear program has a nonempty feasible set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289753/determining-quickly-whether-this-integer-linear-program-has-any-solution-at-all), it is a happy accident that we can arrange for $c_5, \dots, c_8$ to depend only on the negatives of very simple combinations of $c_1, \dots c_4$ and that $c_1 = \cdots = c_4 = 0$ is a point in the feasible set of (II) if the polynomial is in $S$.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! One quick question: would this algorithm still be viable if $S=\{c_1p_1+c_2p_2+...+c_8p_8+1\mid c_1,c_2,...,c_8\geq 0\}$, we loosened the restriction and said $S=\{c_1p_1+c_2p_2+...+c_8p_8+c_9\mid c_1,c_2,...,c_8,c_9 \geq 0\}$? And for my problem the constants are non-negative reals, I wasn't sure what the symbol for that was sorry

Comment: Minor addition, if we add in $c_9$, we do need to restrict it to $c_9\geq 1$ my bad

Comment: The best way to add your $c_9$ is: $c_9 \geq 0$ ; the defining equation for $S$ ends with $c_9+1$ (so $c_9$ has a non=negativity constraint); (I) line 4: ends with "...$c_9+1$" ; to each of the $c_5, \dots, c_8$ equations append "$ - c_9$" ; the left column of (II) is unchanged and in the right column, to each central expression, append "$+c_9$" ; the trivial feasible partial solution becomes $c_1 = \cdots = c_4 = c_9 = 0$.  These changes to the derivation do not change the resulting algorithm.

Comment: Wow you are fantastic, and going above and beyond. I just have one final question. I tried expanding this to the three variable case, which now has triple products. I seem to get stuck solving for the independent constants however (step 3). Here are the equations: $\{x,1-x,y,1-y,z,1-z,1-x-y+xy,1-x-z+xz,1-y-z+yz,y-xy,z-xz,x-xy,z-yz,x-xz,y-yz,xy,xz,yz,1-x-y-z+xy+xz+yz-xyz,z-xz-yz+xyz,y-xy-yz+xyz,x-xy-xz+xyz,yz-xyz,xz-xyz,xy-xyz,xyz\}$ with $c_1,c_2,...,c_{26}$. I know thats a lot, but if Just need to know if its possible/what $c$'s to solve for. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: For the form $a+b x+c y+d z+e x y+f x z+g y z+h x y z$, we solve for $c_{19}, \dots, c_{26}$ to discover $a \geq 0$, $a+d \geq 0$, $a+c \geq 0$, $a+b \geq 0$, $a+c+d+g \geq 0$, $a+b+d+f \geq 0$, $a+b+c+e \geq 0$, $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h \geq 0$. with the trivial assignment $c_1 = \cdots = c_{18} = 0$.  I presume you are using a symbolic linear system solver, like `solve()` in [SciLab](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/solve.html) (or any of many alternatives) to solve for $c_{19}, \dots, c_{26}$ in terms of $a,\dots, g, c_1, \dots, c_{18}$.  Again, luckily, all the $c_i$ appear as $-c_i$.

Comment: How did you decide to solve for $c_{19} ... c_{26}$ instead of, for example $c_{1} ... c_{8}$?

Comment: First, solving for these variables ensures all the others have negative coefficients (as a consequence of how you are constructing your members of $s$).  Second, these are the $c_i$s that control the coefficient $h$ of the monomial $xyz$.  Since $s$ is over-large, we get a (large-ish) set of solutions if the constraints in $a,b,\dots,h$ are not tight, so we have some freedom to pick any set of $c_i$ to solve for.  As a result of basic linear algebra, we can only solve for $|\{a,b,\dots,h\}| = 8$ of them, and happily that is exactly how many elements of $s$ have the monomial of largest degree.

Comment: So say that I had my set of variables come from the following set of equations $\{x_1, 1-x_1, 1-x_1-x_2-x_1x_2,x_1-x_1x_2, x_1x_2, 1-x_1-x_2-x_3+x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3-x_1x_2x_3, x_1-x_1x_2-x_1x_3+x_1x_2x_3, x_2x_3-x_1x_2x_3, x_1x_2x_3\}$. I am now working in the four variable case $w,x,y,z$; i.e. you take those equations above, plug in all combinations of letters, and get the resulting equations (64!!). There are now 64 equations so $c_1p_1+c_2p_2 ... c_{64}p_{64} + 1$. Unfortunately the number of pivot positions is less than the number of monomial equations. Can this method still work?

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions and taking so much time. My eventual goal is to find the inequalities in the event that we have $n$ variables. If this turned out to be doable it would be incredible, and really important

Comment: It would have behooved you to have said what your *actual* problem was in your Question.

Comment: Well my original intention was to ask the simple case, and then work out the harder cases myself, but I still don't fully understand because I've never done linear programming before. Im sorry sir

Comment: You're right about asking the true question, and this was hard enough to have its own question, so I moved it over to here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2843865/426335